# Number of repositories is wrong on Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

After few of repositories were removed from GitHub, and then synced repos on Travis CI, the number of repositories displayed next to the info has stayed the same. Although, the actual repositories are not visible on Travis CI anymore.

Why is that? Is there a way of removing previous repos from Travis CI also just because they were removed already from GitHub?

Comment: *the number of repositories displayed next to the info has stayed the same* Can you please add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

On your [profile page](https://travis-ci.org/profile/alexislefebvre), you can enable or disable repositories:

> [image]

Comment: This does not change the number, when repositories get deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what number you're talking about.